# Inferential properties of Two-Dimensional Kernel Density Estimation

Tags: inference, kernel-smoothing

In r, I create a 70% density contour from a two-dimensional kernel density estimation using

```r
library('MASS')
prob <- .7
dens <- kde2d(x, y, n = 200, lims = c(min(x) - abs(max(x) - min(x)) / 2,
                                      max(x) + (max(x) - min(x)) / 2,
                                      min(y) - abs(max(y) - min(y)) / 2,
                                      max(y) + (max(y) - min(y)) / 2))
dx <- diff(dens$x[1:2])
dy <- diff(dens$y[1:2])
sz <- sort(dens$z)
c1 <- cumsum(sz) * dx * dy 
levels <- sapply(prob, function(x) { 
  approx(c1, sz, xout = 1 - x)$y
})
ls <- contourLines(dens, level = levels)
```

Let's say I draw a random sample from a bivariate population. Ideally, I would like the 70% contour based on the sample to encircle 70% of population, but how well will this procedure actually perform?

I have tried running thousands of iterations using above and noted that on average the specified proportion of the population is encircled by the contour based on the sample (when sample n > 32). However, the encircled proportion in the population varies quite a bit from sample to sample.

I'm a bit unsure of how to specify my question, but maybe one way is to ask if I can create a 95 % confidence interval around the (70%) contour based on the sample? Do you generally think this is a good approach to create a contour estimated to encircle a specified proportion of the population?